# Expand a SingleChildScrollView inside a column to take up as much room as it needs but no more

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter widget like this, with a `SingleChildScrollView` inside a `Column` inside a parent container:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: const Column(
        children: [
          Text("Widget title"),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Text(
              "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
              "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
              "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
              "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
              "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
              "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n",
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to nest that inside another column like this:

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: ...
  body: Column(
    children: [
       Text('Short Text 1'),
       SizedBox(height: 20),
       Text('Short Text 2'),
       SizedBox(height: 20),
       MyWidget(),
       SizedBox(height: 20),
       Text('Short Text 3'),
       SizedBox(height: 20),
       Text('Short Text 4'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

But, the scroll view never scrolls. When the text is too long to fit all the screen, the bottom half of the column gets cut off and I get an overflow error.

[image: bottom overflow example]

Some other answers said to wrap both `MyWidget()` and the `SingleChildScrollView()` in `Expanded()`s. That works great when the text is long, but when the text is short, my widget still expands to take all the available room, which is not the effect I want

[image: too much expansion example]

Is there any way to get the scroll view inside `MyWidget` to shrink as much as needed to fit everything on the screen and expand to take up available room, but **not expand to take up more room than it can fill**?

**Edit:** To be clear, I want the extra whitespace (if there is any) to be at the **end** of the column, as it would be if there were no flexible/scroll components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Flexible` to wrap `MyWidget` and `SingleChildScrollView` then set mainAxisSize `Column` in `MyWidget` to `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` instead of default value (`MainAxisSize.max`) and let the `Column` fills the remaining space.

Wrap with `Flexible`

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: ...
  body: Column(
    children: [
       Text('Short Text 1'),
       SizedBox(height: 20),
       Text('Short Text 2'),
       SizedBox(height: 20),
       // wrap with Flexible
       Flexible(child:MyWidget()),
       SizedBox(height: 20),
       Text('Short Text 3'),
       SizedBox(height: 20),
       Text('Short Text 4'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Wrap `SingleChildScrollView` with `Flexible` and set **Column** `mainAxisSize` to `min` to prevent `Column` from using all remaining space for short text.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: const Column(
        // set mainAxisSize to min
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text("Widget title"),
          // wrap with Flexible
          Flexible(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Text(
                "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
                    "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
                    "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
                    "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
                    "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
                    "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n",
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

For long text

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- We can do that by removing SingleChildScrollView, changing Column to ListView, and setting shrinkWrap to true. (MyWidget)
- On another column, just wrap MyWidget with Flexible
- Short Content
  [image]
- Long Content
  [image]
- Example Code

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: const [
          Text("Widget title"),
          Text(
            "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
            "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
            "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
            "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
            "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
            "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
            "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
            "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n"
            "This is a long piece of text that may or may not fit the screen\n",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
 Scaffold(
  appBar: ...
  body: Column(
    children: [
       Text('Short Text 1'),
       SizedBox(height: 20),
       Text('Short Text 2'),
       SizedBox(height: 20),
       Flexible( child: MyWidget()),
       SizedBox(height: 20),
       Text('Short Text 3'),
       SizedBox(height: 20),
       Text('Short Text 4'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexible instead of Expanded.

> unlike Expanded, Flexible does not require the child to fill the
> available space.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html

Comment: I tried that. If I set `flex: 1` in the Flexible, it behaves exactly like Expanded.  I am aware of the `fit` argument, but that did not make a difference either. If I set flex to 0, I get an error